# Showing an ideal is prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals, ring-isomorphism

I have the ideal $(x-y)$ in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$. One way is to show this ideal is prime is by showing $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x-y)$ is an integral domain. My gut tells me  $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x-y) \cong \mathbb{C}[x,y]$, but I don't know how to define my isomorphism.

Comment: my gut tells me $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x-y) \cong \mathbb{C}[x]$

Comment: What's the intuition behind this? I still feel lost.

Comment: You are basically setting $x=y$ so $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x-y) \cong \mathbb{C}[x,x] \cong \mathbb{C}[x] $

Comment: for one thing, my gut tells me that quotienting by something non-trivial doesn't usually leave the ring unchanged; rather, in the quotient, $x$ is equivalent to $y$ (loosely speaking, you could replace any $y$ with $x$, so $y$ could disappear from all expressions and you're left with $\mathbb C[x]$)

Comment: oh! I see that makes sense. Thank you for the insight.

Comment: kind of like $\mathbb C[x]/(x-3)\cong\mathbb C$, $\mathbb C[x,y]/(x-y)\cong \mathbb C[x][y]/(x-y)\cong \mathbb C[x]\cong\mathbb C[y]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you quotient, you're declaring the thing you're quotienting out to be 0. In your case, everything in the ideal $(y-x)$ becomes zero. Now all elements of this idea are of the form $r \cdot (y-x)$ and once $y-x$ is zero, your intuition should tell you $r \cdot (y-x)$ is zero as well. So what does $y-x=0$ mean? It means $y=x$!

Comment: Oh that makes sense. Then would $\phi(f(x,y)) \to f(x,x)$ be a good isomorphism?

Comment: @HCS that is obviously not 1–1, but you are on the right track. From there you would apply the first isomorphism theorem